# Weird behavior while scraping with NightmareJS - Explication needed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, nightmare

I'm trying to scrape the datas contained on a webpage using Nightmare and so, Electron.

The code is at the bottom of my post ...

I'm starting from this page [Awfully long url](http://www.booking.com/searchresults.fr.html?aid=854594&label=ufi-M1456928&lang=fr&sid=a6c6b41fe01e308cc377e6febeeecfab&sb=1&src=searchresults&src_elem=sb&error_url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.booking.com%2Fsearchresults.fr.html%3Faid%3D854594%3Blabel%3Dufi-M1456928%3Bsid%3Da6c6b41fe01e308cc377e6febeeecfab%3Bcheckin_month%3D3%3Bcheckin_monthday%3D18%3Bcheckin_year%3D2017%3Bcheckout_month%3D4%3Bcheckout_monthday%3D11%3Bcheckout_year%3D2017%3Bcity%3D-1456928%3Bclass_interval%3D1%3Bgroup_adults%3D2%3Bgroup_children%3D0%3Blabel_click%3Dundef%3Bmih%3D0%3Bno_rooms%3D1%3Boffset%3D300%3Broom1%3DA%3Broom2%3DA%3Brows%3D50%3Bsb_price_type%3Dtotal%3Bsrc%3Dsearchresults%3Bsrc_elem%3Dsb%3Bss%3DParis%3Bssb%3Dempty%3Bssne%3DParis%3Bssne_untouched%3DParis%26%3B&ss=Paris&ssne=Paris&ssne_untouched=Paris&city=-1456928&checkin_monthday=18&checkin_month=3&checkin_year=2017&checkout_monthday=1&checkout_month=4&checkout_year=2017&room1=A%2CA&no_rooms=2&group_adults=2&group_children=0&track_sssu=1:).

Where there is a list of hotel room offers.
I want to get the url of the first offer of the page.
(What I'm doing with getOfferUrl()).

Go on it and start my scraping, the purpose of scrapOffer().
The point is I have really weird behaviors that I can explain...

First issue: I had to set my useragent as "Googlebot/2.1" to allow me to go on the offer page,
because when I don't specify any useragent or use the one which is not commented on my code.
Even though I have same URL from getOfferUrl(), I'm staying on the list of offers page.
But I'm going to the page I need to go to, when putting this url in my Chrome browser.

Second issue: When I'm going to the correct offer page, with Googlebot useragent.
There is a div filled, I guess, in jQuery, and where all the infos I need are, which is empty... Why?

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
let cheerio = require('cheerio');
var vo = require("vo");

var getSpecificOfferUrl = Nightmare({ show: true, height: 2400, width: 2400, zoomFactor: 1.0});
var scrap = Nightmare({ show: true, height: 2400, width: 2400, zoomFactor: 1.0});

var offer = {};
var offersListUrl = "http://www.mywebsite.url";

function getOfferUrl(offersListUrl) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        getSpecificOfferUrl
            .goto(offersListUrl)
            .wait(1000)
            .end()
            .evaluate(function() {
                var newUrl = document.querySelector('.hotel_name_link').href;
                return (newUrl);
            })
            .then(function(newUrl) {
                resolve(newUrl);
        })
    })
}

function scrapOffer(newUrl) {
    scrap
        .useragent('Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.76 Safari/537.36')
        // .useragent('Googlebot/2.1')
        .goto(newUrl)
        .wait(3000)
        .end()
        .evaluate(function() {
            var html = document.querySelector('#right').innerHTML;
            return (html);
        })
        .then(function(html) {
            $ = cheerio.load(html);
            offer['title'] = $('h1').text().trim();
        })
    return Promise.resolve(offer)
}
console.log("start");
vo(getOfferUrl, scrapOffer)(offersListUrl).then(offer => {
    console.log(offer);
    console.log("end");
});
```

Comment: You _might_ want to start by looking in `scrapOffer` - you're returning a resolved promise with a (likely) empty `offer` object immediately before the `scrap` instance has a chance to run.  I'll post a more formal answer when I can tinker with the source under test.